# Variable Naming Convention for Find and Replace in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering which is the best naming convention to use if I want to rename variables with find and replace, without worrying about making mistakes because of substrings. For example find and replace on "myVariable" to "myNumber" will rename the variable "myVariableGroup" to myNumberGroup.

I'm thinking of using a character at the end to indicate the end of the variable such as "myVariable_i" which has the added benefit of being used to identify the type of variable.

Surely a convention that does this exists and I just can't find it right?

Comment: Picking a project-wide naming convention just because you might someday want to use find and replace seems a bit overkill, no? Use a regex for your find that doesn't allow word characters after your identifier.

Comment: What type of data will these placeholders appear in?  Knowing the type of data can help determine how complicated the placeholders have to be.  Usually, though, placeholders are a string enclosed in marching characters (open-close braces, for example) or identical weird characters (like an @-sign).  Just to confirm, though, although you'll be doing the search and replace in JavaScript, the actual strings you'll be processing are not JavaScript, right?  Planing to do search and replace in source code is probably not a great idea.  There, you're probably better off doing s full parse

Comment: sorry I should have clarified, I actually meant the names of JS variables and find and replace in the source code, not with any JS function. I think using a regex solves my problem... I just didn't know I could search that way :S

Comment: Its a pretty dangerous proposition using simple regular expressions to edit symbol names in a program.  You really should be doing a full parse, modifying the AST, and spitting out the resulting program.  That all said, I'm curious why you would need to rename variable names in a program so often you feel it necessary to have a proper naming convention that makes this easy.  Usually you name a variable based on the purpose/meaning/expected use of its value.  Are you suggesting the purposes of your program's variables will change often, out of the blue?

Comment: ctt, you are right. The reason my program changes so often is because I am a beginner in JS and when I realise that there is a better way to structure something, I want to change the variable name to match. I'm not sure how to modify the AST in dreamweaver but I'll look into that :)

Answer (score -1):

you can find with match case and whole word to replace it with particular word so that other variable stated here as chance of replacing from `myVariableGroup` to `myNumberGroup` should not take place.

attached snapshot to find and replace in in netbeans IDE:

[image: netbeans find and replace snapshot]